# Effects package equivalent for LCMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, latent-class, effects

The `effects` package helps in the analysis of predictor effects from LMER models. Is there an equivalent for LCMM models? (i.e. understand predictor effects of class specific variables and within class variables)